# Can these equations be solved via substitution?

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have eight equations with variables $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}:$
$$a*b*c*d=64\\
b+c+d-e=6\\
a*e=8\\
b+f=6\\
b*f=8\\
c*g=8\\
d+h=9\\
d*h=8$$

I know there are 4 solutions, but is there any deterministic way of solving these?  I would like to figure out the first step that naturally leads to at least one of the variables being solved for. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you have two equations involving only $b$ and $f$, and two involving only $d$ and $h$.  This is probably a good place to start.

For each of these mini-systems, there will be two solutions, which gives four solutions for the variables $b,d,f,$ and $h$.  If there are indeed only four solutions, then the other four variables should be completely determined having chosen a solution for $b,d,f,$ and $h$.

Comment: Indeed - once $b,d$ are known, we have equations for $ac$ and $ae$ which gives $e=kc$ for some constant $k$, and also for $c-e$ - this gives unique values for $a, c, e$ (provided you don't end up dividing by zero). Finally $g$ is obtained from $cg=8$